# Excel Solver - Limit variable results to the tenths place only

Tags: excel, solver

I am trying to use excel solver to calculate a total number of hours by person when as well as some of their rates when I am provided with the Total Amount and I already know some of the rates.

[Screenshot of worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw8cz.png)

I know the following constraints will apply:

-Rates must integers divisible by 5

-Hours must be rounded to the tenth's place

-Rates will have a ">=" value depending on the worker

Thoughts on how to constrain the results to the variable cells this way so the rates will end in 5 or 0, and the hours will only stop at the tenth's place instead of returning 4.99663675 as a result?

Comment: If those are the only calculations, what do you need the solver for? Show what you are really doing.

Comment: Add some more details here. Screenshot what you're doing and highlightt he solved cell. With the description you've provided, you could just do `=ROUND(Amount/Hourly Rate, 1)`